# Scala iterator.count for large lists (>int32 size)

Tags: scala

I have large lists that I need to get the size of. Count returns an int, according to the scala api https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.3/scala/collection/immutable/List.html, which may overflow on large lists.

How do I get around this?

Comment: Is there actually a list of that size, or is this a hypothetical..? Counting a (linked) list is also O(n).. anyway, a long count value could be counted with `fold/foldLeft`.

Comment: This is not hypothetical. I'm migrating a system to scala that will have up to 10 billion ids to keep track of and generate internal incrementing ids for

I guess we have to use the manual way and not rely on the api

Comment: That sounds like an awful lot to keep in memory. Also note that `length` is an O(n) operation. Perhaps a different structure / algorithm (not needing the length) might be more suitable. Good luck.

Comment: The API will be really slow, so counting them on the way in is also a pretty good optimisation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution could be:

```
aList.foldLeft(0L)((acc, _) => acc + 1)
```

This will return the total number of elements as a Long number.
If you want, you can wrap this functionality with the Pimp my library pattern:

```
implicit class LongList[A](list: List[A]) {
  def sizeL: Long = list.foldLeft(0L)((acc, _) => acc + 1)
}
```

As underlying in the comments, this operation will cost you `O(n)`, so if you have other alternatives try to explore them :)